# Error "latexmk: The script engine could not be found" in VS Code using MikTeX 2.9

Tags: latexmk, miktex2.9, ide

LaTeX-Workshop on VS Code keeps printing this error:

> latexmk: The script engine could not be found.
>   latexmk: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe", scriptName="latexmk"

I installed 'latexmk' via MikTeX 2.9, yet it still gives me this message. What do I have to do?

Comment: Do you have [*perl*](https://www.perl.org/get.html#win32)  installed on your system?

Comment: Oh I thought it came with either MikTeX or latexmk...thanks!

Comment: See as well https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462365/how-to-use-latex-on-vs-code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quick summary:

1. Install Perl from [The Perl Programming Language](https://perl.org). [ActiveState Perl](https://www.activestate.com/products/perl/) is recommended for beginners. Make sure to add the Perl local directory to your system Path.
2. Install the `latexmk` package with your TeX distribution.

Comment: If you had used texlive instead of miktex, perl would have been included.

Comment: @daleif perfectly true, however many OLD install instructions still assume MiKTeX includes Perl as it formerly did. It may be worth mentioning that like TeX Live is "fuller" than incremental TeX such as W32 or Tiny or MiKTeX equally the fuller version of Perl should be the Strawberry flavour but **MiKTeX plus ActiveState** will be good enough for most latexmk on windows users.

Comment: K. Paul it may be worth mentioning that there are two things to check after installing Perl 1) check perl has included itself on the system path 2) check that the path is **not terminated** by a final semicolon; as this can supposedly upset latexmk searching beyond end of ; separated path for a non existent final entry.

Answer (score 3):

That error occur because VS Code can't find `perl` (on your environment path).

You can test if it's exist or not using:

```bash
perl -v
```

If you already install MikTeX and VSCode, I suggest you install perl via [Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/).

Step by step `Strawberry Perl` installation for windows based on this [source](https://learn.perl.org/installing/windows.html) is:

1. Make sure you do not have any version of Perl already installed. Check both `add/remove programs` and `C:\Strawberry`.
2. Download `msi` file. As for this writing, choose between `strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit.msi` or `strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-32bit.msi`, same as your system (64 or 32).
3. Install.

To test your installation is success and `Path` already added, test using:

```bash
perl -v
```

Note:
I already try install `perl` using `ActiveState Perl`, and the *error persist*. This is due to `ActiveState` installation will use `ActiveState` environment and does not add `perl` to `Path`. This might help a new user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: One more potential pitfall: I updated "latex-workshop.latex.tools" in my VS Code "settings.json" to set env.PATH to include the Perl path. I still got the above error. When I changed the name of the environment variable from "PATH" to "Path", things started working.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you did that?

Comment: @Tera what do you want to be cleared? Installing `Strawberry Perl` on windows will automatically setup environment `Path` on my case.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni I installed perl as explained by you and if I check via "perl -v" in the terminal everything is fine. Yet, VSC still does not find the perl.exe. So I wanted to try onnodb's approach, but I do not know what exactly to write into the "settings.json" file.