# Magic comment doesn't seem to work in VScode?

Tags: xetex, vscode

I'm tyring to built a tex project in VScode. One problem I encountered is that I need to write in Chinese and as such I need to specify the compiler as xelatex rathter than pdflatex. This is not a problem when I'm using texshop, the default IDE I used before, since it allows you to choose the prefered compiler manually. But I don't know how to do that in VScode. So what I do is I added a magic comment in my root file

> % !TEX program = xelatex

This is supposed to work, and if my memory served me right, it seems to work before. But for whatever reason, it is no longer working. When I tried to run my tex file, it throws a bunch of 122(!)errors like

> Package inputenc: Unicode character 学 (U+5B66)
> (inputenc)  not set up for use with LaTeX.

I am not sure what went wrong with my magic comment and more importantly, how to force VScode to use xelatex.

On [this link](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#latex-workshoplatexrecipedefault), you can see the author of latex workshop extention recommend the use of recipe, but honestly I am most confused about where to find the recipe mentioned in the FAQ page and how to edit it.

The author also mentions that magic comment should work as well.

> Suppose there is a line % !TEX program = xelatex in the root file. Upon building the project, LaTeX Workshop will parse the root file and figure out that xelatex should be used.

I am on Macbook mid 2014 with texlive 2020. in case this is relevant.

Also, here is my sourcecode. I don't think it is much relevant as I have tried to compile the sourcefile using texshop and it works just fine. So I'm sure it is because of the compiler I chose.

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{My literature.bib} 
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\title{学会学习}
\date{}
\maketitle
\newsavebox\watermarkbox
\lhead{BeyondWorld Education}
\rfoot{学会学习}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}


 \section{前言}
 \input{./section/preface}


\section{学习的生物学基础}


\section{如何学习}


\section{如何学习英语}
\subsection{单词本}
\input{./section/单词本}

\section{应试技巧}

\end{document}
```

edit: someone on reddit points me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56109128/enable-xelatex-in-latex-workshops-for-visual-studio-code)
But VScode still throws errors, and I don't think I have successfuly forced VScode to use xelatex instead.
[image]
And this is my VScode settings.json file that I assume I need to edit.
[image]

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462365/how-to-use-latex-on-vs-code , about the `settings.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

Magic comments have been disabled by default since December 29, 2021 due to a security risk. Enable it by setting:

```
latex-workshop.latex.build.forceRecipeUsage: false
```

Ref: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/3027.