# Sorry, but latexmk did not succeed for the following reason:MiKTeX could not find the script engine 'perl.exe' which is required to execute 'latexmk'

Tags: errors, perl

LaTeX workshop on vscode keeps showing this error:

Sorry, but latexmk did not succeed for the following reason:

> MiKTeX could not find the script engine 'perl.exe' which is required to execute 'latexmk'.

Remedy:

> Make sure 'perl.exe' is installed on your system.

But i have installed  `perl.exe` to my windows computer via `strawberryperl`. How can I make MiKTeX find `perl.exe`? Similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461954/error-latexmk-the-script-engine-could-not-be-found-in-vs-code-using-miktex-2) asked before but in that case he/she didn't installed `perl.exe`, but i did and it gives me error.please  help me to fix this error.

[image: Here is Perl.exe]

Comment: Usually these kinds of issues can be resolved by making sure that the directory of perl.exe is included in the PATH variable of your Windows user account.If you used the portable version of strawberry perl I suspect that this is the root cause (the installer would probably extend PATH for you).

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Comment: AFAIK you are allowed to anwer your own questions.... so you could write up an answer yourself below. Feel free from my side!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue with @0x6d64's help. Just need to add directory of `perl.exe` to PATH variable. Go to PATH variable select New and type(if you installed `strawberry` with defaul settings otherwise type where's your `perl` folder)

`C:\Strawberry\perl`

and issue is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Just to weigh in for those a bit computer-iliterate like me. the PATH variable is in the control panel > system settings > advanced system settings > evironmental setting. Also one will need to do a restart of the computer to make it work.